# Multi-line macro resolving to one line in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm, preprocessor

I'm not sure how I should name this thread, so let me explain my question on an example first.

I've been trying to create a macro taking an arbitrary number of arguments and returning the index of the smallest one (with regard to the initial indexing).

Since indexing is more of a technical thing, I'll post an example returning the minimum instead.

```
%macro FIND_MIN 1-*
    %assign %%MIN %1
    %rep %0
        %if %1 < %%MIN
            %assign %%MIN %1
        %endif
        %rotate 1
    %endrep

    %%MIN
%endmacro
```

Everything would be good if not for the fact that this

```
MY_MIN equ FIND_MIN 21, 7, 13
```

doesn't work. NASM says: "bad syntax for EQU". Trying to use `%define`/`%xdefine` doesn't result in anything "valid" either.

To return to my general question, I wonder if it's possible to enforce a multi-line macro to resolve to something that could work in contexts such as `equ`. I've tried to find similar questions on the internet, but with little success (to be honest, it's quite surprising to me that the only resources about metaprogramming in NASM Google pulls up are mostly just NASM's documentation pages).

Thank you in advance.

PS. One solution that actually works for me is first "x-defining" a variable and using a macro to modify it, but that results in very inconvenient and ugly code such as

```
%xdefine GLOBAL_MIN 0

%macro FIND_MIN 1-*
    ; find the min and %xdefine GLOBAL_MIN NEW_MIN
%endmacro

FIND_MIN 20, 3, 12
C equ GLOBAL_MIN
```

Comment: The initial `%xdefine GLOBAL_MIN 0` isn't needed. Other than that your suggestion is pretty much what I'd assume the best answer is. In my macro collection I use multi-line macros like `numdef` and `lvar` which accept an initial parameter that specifies the single-line macro name to use. Because of how NASM handles them I always prefix the smacro name with something else, like `_` for `numdef` and `?` for `lvar`. So if you pass `numdef OPTION, 1` it will make a numeric define defaulting to 1, which can be used like `%if _OPTION`.

Comment: @ecm: Can you write a macro that takes an "output" variable as the first arg, like `FIND_MIN  MIN_RESULT, 20, 3, 12`, then `C equ MIN_RESULT`.  That avoids an implicit name for the "return value".  But yeah, NASM unfortunately doesn't have function-like macros that take args and evaluate to a value you can use as an operand for something else.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you can, however if the smacro name like `MIN_RESULT` is already in use from a prior invocation then `%define %1 foo` will fail. This is why I use the prefixes like `%define _%1 foo` or `%define ?%1 foo`